# Does pyqt text edit has a font overline property

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I know that PyQt QTextChar format has a font overline property but pyqt textedit

has only font italic,bold and underline.Does textEdit font overline exists??

then what is the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes it has,

try something like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.text_edit = QTextEdit("Overlining...")
        self.text_edit.setStyleSheet("""
            text-decoration: overline;
        """)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wid = Widget()
    wid.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You have a lot of other [properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) and [examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html) you can have a look.

---

There are some other approaches, one of them is instead of making use of stylesheet you can set the "html" [properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html) of its [qdocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html), having something like this:

```
self.text_edit = QTextEdit()
personalized_document = QTextDocument()
personalized_document.set...#set all you need for example the overline you need.
self.text_edit.setDocument(personalized_document)
```

Comment: just one more thing.how to get the value of stylesheet.I mean in QTextchar format you would do something like print formats.fontItalic()

Comment: I don't know if it's exactly what you want but after setting your stylesheet you can access the properties it has using `self.text_edit.styleSheet()` and it'll return a string with these properties. Or you can make something like `self.text_edit.font()` and it'll return a `QFont ` object, from there you can have the `pointSize`, and many other properties from `QFont`. Not only `QFont()` but you can access the `QColor` of it, `QBrush`, and many others.. Does it help or it's not what you are willing to figure out?